# Does BIOS need to be loaded into main memory to be executed by CPU?

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, bios

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) says

> Originally, BIOS firmware was stored in **a ROM chip** on the PC motherboard. In modern computer systems, the BIOS contents are stored on **flash memory** so it can be rewritten without removing the chip from the motherboard.

When BIOS is stored in either a ROM chip or a flash memory, does BIOS need to be loaded into main memory to be executed by CPU?  Or can CPU execute BIOS directly in ROM or flash memory?

Comment: BIOS flash is a type called "NOR" (as opposed to NAND) that supports byte-level updating and "execute in place."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory

Comment: flash is ROM.  <--.  You can say lash is EEPROM, but EEPROM is ROM, by definition

Answer (score 3):

Early BIOS executes directly from the flash chip. The address of the flash chip is mapped to overlap with the [Reset Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_vector). Later, for second and third stage bootloaders, BIOS will copy itself into processor cache and finally RAM.

A very detailed guide of modern processor booting is available [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/booting-an-intel-architecture-system-par/232300699). This is to some extent reflected in the [Intel Software Development Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) and the Intel BIOS Writer's Guide. AMD, ARM, VIA, etc. produce equivalent guides for their processors.